# Git rebase or merge doesn't change a file at the second time

Tags: git, merge, rebase

This question accurately resembles this question: [Git merge doesn't merge a file the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329803/git-merge-doesnt-merge-a-file-the-second-time)

I will just copy and paste the original question since it describes the background of my question:

*I have a master branch with some stuff, let's say file README. I also have a dev branch, child of master, with some additional files, let's say file README2. I do the following:
git merge dev
from master and get the file README2 merged into master. Now I remove it:
git rm README2
Now when I merged dev again, I expected that I will get README2 file merged into master, because it's not in the master anymore. But Git reports there are no changes and nothing to merge. This actually suits me, but I don't understand how is this so, since branch dev at this point clearly has README2 file, while master doesn't.*

However, I'm not asking why it happens, I understand that git rebase/merge works at the level of the commit tree, not of individual files, but I would like to ask - in this instance, how would you get back the README2 file from branch `dev` ? Or in other words, is there a simple way to re-apply the merge as if it happens the first time, without having to delete commits?

EDIT: to put it another way, is there a way to overwrite the files with the files in the other branch, while being asked to solve conflicts? (the exact functionality of using merge)

Comment: The simple answer is: You `git revert` the commit that removed the file.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, but in case I don't remember what I changed, there's no way to somehow overwrite my files with the other branch files while asking to solve conflicts (exactly like with merge) ?

Comment: Fwiw the format of this question is quite poor. it would benefit from the edit being reworded as the title and showing, not describing, the situation. It’s an odd/confusing choice to quote a different question.

Answer (score 1):

> how would you get back the `README2` file from branch `dev`

You could use the new [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) command ([Git 2.23, Q3 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)), and restore the missing file after your merge:

```
git switch main
git restore -s dev -- ./README2
# add and commit
```